# how to change button text by onclick in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my coding, I have a button Text as "Invite" for each user.

When I on click the button, the button text should be change as 
'Pending Request", by using document.getElementById()
the first button text is changing. What my requirement is what all the button I am clicking the particular button text should be change.

But for me the First button text alone changing when clicking other buttons.

Here is a coding:

**Html code:**

```
<div class="button_wrapper">
     <input onclick="getInvitevalue(__iProfId__)" type="button" value="Invite" name="InviteTeacher" class="InviteTeacher" id= "InviteTeacher"/>              
</div>
```

**Java Script code:**

```
function getInvitevalue(profileid) {
    //alert(profileid);
    var x = document.getElementById("InviteTeacher");
    if (x.value == "Pending Request")
        x.value = "Invite";
    else
        x.value = "Pending Request";
}
```

How I can resolve this

Comment: This is a JS question.. consider retagging it if u want JS answers :)

Answer (score 3):

What you need is a toggle mechanic on that button. Something like this with jQuery would do the trick:

```
$('#InviteTeacher').toggle(function(){
    $(this).val('Pending Request');
}, function(){
    $(this).val('Invite');
});
```

You can take a look at this working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6qydD/).

---

UPDATE:

If you need this behavior for many similar buttons, using the class attribute would be a much nicer choice than the id attribute. In that case, you could have a markup like this:

```
<input type="button" value="Invite" name="InviteTeacher" class="InviteButton" />
<input type="button" value="Invite" name="InviteStudent1012" class="InviteButton" />
<input type="button" value="Invite" name="InviteStudent2230" class="InviteButton" />
<input type="button" value="Invite" name="InviteStudent3125" class="InviteButton" />
```

That will have little effect on the script:

```
$('.InviteButton').toggle(function(){
    $(this).val('Pending Request');
}, function(){
    $(this).val('Invite');
});
```

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: how could if I use id= "InviteTeacher(__iProfId__)" in html form. It will assign dynamic id for each user know. For this id, how to use getElementById(), or toggle, or bind. Is their chance to write id value with another id as ('#InviteTeacher' + profileid) in toggle function

Comment: @AnneTina If predefined IDs need to be selected, you can include them by separing different value with a comma (`,`), for example : `$('#InviteTeacher, #InviteStudent')`. If there are many similar buttons, I would recommend using the class attribute, though, since you really don't want to deal with many similar IDs.

Comment: I just updated my answer, I hope this is closer to what you are looking for.

Comment: For me id="InviteTeacher(profileid), its output is id="InviteTeacher(36)", id="InviteTeacher(3)" id="InviteTeacher(37)" the profile id is dynamic value depends on users id in database. In this case how could i pass the dynamic value of profile id with InviteTeacher. In Ajax we post the dynamic value means how can post the id

Comment: Is there something missing in the question? Please post all the relevant information so everyone can understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

You can use java script like this:

**Html Code:**

```
<div class="button_wrapper">
    <input onclick="getInvitevalue(this.id)" type="button" value="Invite" name="InviteTeacher" class="InviteTeacher" id="InviteTeacher" />
    <input onclick="getInvitevalue(this.id)" type="button" value="Invite" name="InviteTeacher" class="InviteTeacher" id="InviteTeacher(36)" />
    <input onclick="getInvitevalue(this.id)" type="button" value="Invite" name="InviteTeacher" class="InviteTeacher" id="InviteTeacher(37)" />
    <input onclick="getInvitevalue(this.id)" type="button" value="Invite" name="InviteTeacher" class="InviteTeacher" id="InviteTeacher(3)" />
</div>
```

**Java Script Code:**

```
<script>
    function getInvitevalue(profileid) {
        //alert(profileid);
        var x = document.getElementById(profileid);
        if (x.value == "Pending Request") x.value = "Invite";
        else x.value = "Pending Request";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: For me id="InviteTeacher(profileid), its output is id="InviteTeacher(36)", id="InviteTeacher(3)" id="InviteTeacher(37)" the profile id is dynamic value depends on users id in database. In this case how could i pass the dynamic value of profile id with InviteTeacher. In Ajax we post the dynamic value means how can post the id

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do:

```
<div class="button_wrapper">
    <input onclick="getInvitevalue(123)" type="button" value="Invite" name="InviteTeacher" class="InviteTeacher123" id= "InviteTeacher"/>              
</div> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    function getInvitevalue(id) {
        var button = document.getElementsByClassName("InviteTeacher" + id)[0];
        if (button.value === "Pending Request") {
            button.value = "Invite";
        } else {
            button.value = "Pending Request";
        }
    }
</script>
```

It has been [tested](http://jsfiddle.net/shawn31313/y7g33/1/). You can pass `this` into the parameter of a function inside of attribute event to define itself. In this case, `this` is equivalent to: `document.getElementById("InviteTeacher")`

Script in jQuery (it is tagged):

```
<div class="button_wrapper">
    <input type="button" value="Invite" name="InviteTeacher" class="InviteTeacher123" id= "InviteTeacher"/>              
</div> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("input[class^='InviteTeacher']").bind("click", function () {
        var button = $(this);
        if (button.val() === "Pending Request") {
            button.val("Invite");
        } else {
            button.val("Pending Request");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: how could if I use id= "InviteTeacher(iProfId)" in html form. It will assign dynamic id for each user know. For this id, how to use getElementById(), or toggle, or bind. Is their chance to write id value with another dynamic id.

Answer (score 0):

You could use class name for achieving this:

HTML:

```
<div class="button_wrapper">
       <input type="button" value="Invite" name="InviteTeacher" class="InviteTeacher" id= "InviteTeacher1"/>    
    <input type="button" value="Invite" name="InviteTeacher" class="InviteTeacher" id= "InviteTeacher2"/>   
    <input type="button" value="Pending Request" name="InviteTeacher" class="InviteTeacher" id= "InviteTeacher3"/>   
   </div>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $('div.button_wrapper').on('click', '.InviteTeacher', function(){
        if(this.value == 'Pending Request')
             $(this).val('Invite');
    })
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/H96sB/1/

**Update:**

Replace the jquery function with this:

```
   function getInvitevalue(idValue){
    $('div.button_wrapper').on('click', '#InviteTeacher'+idValue, function(){
        if(this.value == 'Pending Request')
             $(this).val('Invite');
    });
  }
```

Comment: how could if I use id= "InviteTeacher(iProfId)" in html form. It will assign dynamic id for each user know. For this id, how to use getElementById(), or toggle, or bind. Is their chance to write id value with another dynamic id.

Comment: ya I checked this site their it's working fine but for my source its not working.

Comment: For me id="InviteTeacher(profileid), its output is id="InviteTeacher(36)", id="InviteTeacher(3)" id="InviteTeacher(37)" the profile id is dynamic value depends on users id in database. In this case how could i pass the dynamic value of profile id with InviteTeacher. In Ajax we post the dynamic value means how can post the id

Comment: What error are you getting in the firebug?. Are you putting the code outside the `document.ready()` function, because the onclick event will be executed before the jquery `document.ready()`.

Comment: No actions on onclick and getting console error of jquery/webforms.js and functions.js files affecting

Comment: Post the error screen shot link so it would be easier to debug. Try checking whether the error related to the function which I posted? . Try putting alert inside the function to ensure it is getting called.